# Python : How to generate the combination of columns in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding iteration and combination in Pandas

I have the following dataframe like this

```
df1:
flavor_1   flavor_2  flavor_3 flavor_4 flavor_5 flavor_6 flavor_7 flavor_8 flavor_9 price id
Lime        Lemon      Grape     Grass   Nan     Nan       Nan       Nan     Nan      80   1  
Lime        Peach      Nan     Nan     Nan     Nan       Nan       Nan     Nan      89      2
Lime        Plum      Grape     Grass   Vanilla Plum      Fig       Olive   Cherry   81     3
Lime        Black      Grape     Grass   Plum     Fig       Nan       Nan     Nan      84   4
.
.
.
.
Lime        Lemon      Grape     Grass   Nan     Nan       Nan       Nan     Nan      80   300
```

I want to generate a new data frame with all possible combinations of two columns in the SAME ROW. For example,

```
df_new:
Target   Source Price  id 
Lemon     Grape  80     1
Lemon     Grass  80     1
Grape     Grass  80     1
Plum      Grape  81     3    
Plum      Grass  81     3
.
.
.
.
Lemon     Grape  80   300
Lemon     Grass  80   300
Grap      Grass  80   300
```

Thus, I tried this code t

```
import itertools
def comb(df1):
    return [df1.loc[:, list(x)].set_axis(['Target','Source'], axis=1)
            for x in itertools.combinations(df1.columns, 2)]
```

However, I could't get proper Dataframe that I need.

I want not only combination of columns in same row, but also price&ID in that row.
Also, I want to delete a row with combination with NaN
Is there any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (df.set_index(['price','id'])
        .stack()
        .groupby(level=[0,1])
        .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(x, 2), 
                                      columns=['Target','Source']))
        .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
        .reset_index()[['Target','Source','price','id']])
    
print (df)
   Target Source  price  id
0    Lime  Lemon     80   1
1    Lime  Grape     80   1
2    Lime  Grass     80   1
3   Lemon  Grape     80   1
4   Lemon  Grass     80   1
..    ...    ...    ...  ..
59  Grape    Fig     84   4
60  Grass   Plum     84   4
61  Grass    Fig     84   4
62   Plum    Fig     84   4
63   Lime  Peach     89   2

[64 rows x 4 columns]
```